# Как в ListView обработать нажатие кнопки и изменить здесь же значение в textView

Tags: android, listview, view

У меня есть `ListView`, у него есть своя разметка на которой находится строчки на каждой из которых `Button` и `textView`. Как мне обработать нажатие кнопки и изменить здесь же значение в `textView`, например было в `textView` "0" станет "1".

Comment: если приведете пример, как вы формируете ListView, например код адаптера :) то я в вашем же коде и поправлю все :)

Comment: @Override
  protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson)
 {
   try 
{
    jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
    NewsJSONParser newsJsonParser = new NewsJSONParser();
    newsJsonParser.parse(jObject);
   } 
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("JSON Exception1", e.toString());
   }

   NewsJSONParser newsJsonParser = new NewsJSONParser();
   List<HashMap<String, Object>> untries = null;
   try {
    untries = newsJsonParser.parse(jObject);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
   }

Comment: String[] from = { "text", "image", "tails", "dikes" };
   
   int[] to = { R.id.tv_c, R.id.iv_image, R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2 };
   

   SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(),
     untries, R.layout.v_layout, from, to);
   return adapter;
  }

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример адаптера

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private List<String> Strings;

    //resource - это id вашего list item, a Strings - это строки, которые будут отображаться в TextView
    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> Strings) {

        super(context, resource, Strings);

        this.Strings = Strings;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.v_layout, null);

        }

        String p = Strings.get(position);

        if (p != null) {

            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.your_TextView);
            Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.your_button);
            button.setTag(tt);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    ((TextView)v.getTag()).setText("ist click");
                }
            });

            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText(p);
            }

        }

        return v;

    }
```

Тут как его использовать на примере вашего кода

```
@Override protected ListAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) 
{ 
try 
{ 
    jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]); 
    NewsJSONParser newsJsonParser = new NewsJSONParser(); 
    newsJsonParser.parse(jObject); 
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{ 
     Log.d("JSON Exception1", e.toString());
 }
        NewsJSONParser newsJsonParser = new NewsJSONParser();
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> untries = null;
        try {
            untries = newsJsonParser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        String[] from = { "text", "image", "tails", "dikes" };

        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                untries, R.layout.v_layout, Arrays.asList(from));
        return adapter;
    }
```

ЗЫ: Могут быть синтаксические ошибки, так как писал в блокноте, но логика должна быть примерно ясна

Comment: ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                untries, R.layout.v_layout, Arrays.asList(from));
        return adapter;

вот это не прокатывает, ошибка здесь.

Comment: И вообще не понимаю как всё это использовать. Какие классы создавать или где код поменять. Сложно мне...

Comment: Вот у меня есть проект: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/?wpdmact=process&did=MTcxLmhvdGxpbms=

в нем ToggleButton, может кто поможет его переделать под обычные кнопки?

Comment: популярнее объясните логику: нажал кнопку - изменился текст, а дальше что Вы будете делать с этим текстом и самим списком, быть может кнопка и вовсе не нужна