# Как обработать клик по элементу в ListView

Tags: java, android

Имеется ListView, состоящий из 2 EditText. Необходимо обработать нажатие на элемент ListView.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал делать через событие onClick в EditText:

```
// Метод, обрабатывающий клик на один из EditText'ов
public void onClickDbResource(View view) {
    EditText etResource = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvResource);

    String resourceInEdit = edittextResource.getText().toString();
    // Метод для дропа в Clipbrd
    CopyToClipboard(resourceInView);
}
```

Метод работал, но бросал значения не соотвутствующие выбранному item'у.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не совсем ясно, нужно обработать нажатие по ListView или по EditText в ListView?

Обработка событий ListView:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
        // Logics
      }
});
```

**UPD:**

- parent – View-родитель для нажатого пункта
- view – это нажатый пункт
- position – порядковый номер пункта в списке
- id – идентификатор элемента

**UPD2:**

В Вашем случае понадобится кастомизированный список со своим адаптером.

- [Android ListView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)
- [Кастомизация списка. Создаем свой адаптер](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html)
- [Пример адаптера с кнопкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/215556/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-listview-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-textview)

Comment: У меня из БД дропаются resource(в 1-ый EditText) и password(во 2). Мне необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на любой выбранный EditText текст с него копировался в буфер обмена.

Comment: Как самый простой вариант, с БД в массив из массива в ListView, при нажатии на item брался из массива по порядковый номер пункта в списке

Comment: А вообще почитайте про ListView и про адаптеры

Comment: [как вариант](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html)

Comment: [startandroid.ru](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html)

Comment: Примерно похожий [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/215556/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-listview-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-textview)

Comment: Спасибо за предложенные варианты. Получится - отпишусь.

Answer (score 4):

Получилось!

Разметка файла `item.xml`, который определяет структуру `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/Resource"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

В `OnItemClickListener`обрабатываю нажатие на элемент `ListView`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            // Заменил EditText на TextView
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Password);
            // Берём значение TextView
            String text = textView.getText().toString();
            // И копируем в буфер
            SaveToClipboard(text);
        }
    });
```

> Пример работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Инициализировать TextView нужно в onCreate

Comment: @ВладимирSeos-Lab, объясните поподробнее почему именно в onCreate?

Comment: onCreate() задает начальную установку параметров при инициализации активности,  вызывается при первом создании активности. А в Вашем случае инициализация происходит при каждом клике.

Comment: @ВладимирSeos-Lab, Ок, спасибо, подправил.

Comment: Метод `findViewById()` очень ресурсоемкий для системы и вызывать его надо как можно реже, обычно все ссылки на виджеты получают один раз в `onCreate()` и хранят их в полях класса для быстрого доступа из любого метода этого класса

Comment: @pavlofff Т.е. надо делать следующее: в классе сделать `EditText et;`, а в `onCreate` написать `et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password)`?

Comment: Да, так же и для всех других виджетов